# How do I interpret this printf in C

Tags: c

I am going through some code where I got stuck reading a printf statement:

```
printf("%*s%s\n", stat[type].dent, "", buf);
```

`states[type].indent` is a number which is equal to 4 and `buf` is buffer of 215 bytes with 0 strored into it as string but not sure `""` and `%*s`  is meant for.

Can anybody help me reading this `printf` statement?

Comment: You interpret it by reading the documentation on printf.

Comment: Only 5 answers? This is such low hanging fruit, surely we can get a lot more. (Me, I voted to close.)

Comment: why do you not try it? write an exmaple code like: `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%*s%s\n", i, "", "Amit Singh Tomar");` and check its output

Comment: Thanks Grijesh ,Your comment made quite a sense.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar but thing is why output so? important is `"%*s"` same as `"%2s"` if `i` == `2` and same as `"%3s"` if `i` == `3`. The concept is called dynamic padding. Try [this code - compile and run](http://hildebrando.net/trac/browser/c/wrox/printdir.c)

Answer (score 2):

The `*` in the format code `"%*s"` tells `printf` that the next argument is a field width followed by the normal argument (a string in this case).

It's the same as e.g. `"%4s"` in your case, but the width can be set in runtime.

So here `stat[type].dent` is the field width, and the empty string is the string. So this prints the empty string with 4 characters width (so you get four spaces) followed by whatever is in `buf`.

I recommend a good [reference on `printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) where it's all documented.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` means that the width of the argument to be printed is dependent on an (integer) argument that precedes it.

From [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

```
printf ("Width trick: %*d \n", 5, 10); // 5 is the width, 10 is the integer being printed
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%*s` is a string conversion. The `*` part means that a width for the field will be supplied as a parameter (that's how `stat[type].dent` is used). So it's printing an empty string in some specified width (call it N). In other words, its leaves N blank spaces before printing out `buf`.

Comment: The only answer that bothers to say ... or even think about ... what this does and what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

`*` will get replaced by value of `stat[type].dent` which is a number and will be known as minimum field width.

Answer (score 0):

It is a precision, which specifies maximum number of bytes for string conversions.

Asterisk (*), uses an integer argument, which specifies the value (for precision) to be used.

To print a string for a variable length,specify`printf("%*s", l, string)`. The `l` is substituted for the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

`"%*s%s\n"` is a format that contains **3 directives**.

`"%*s"`

This directive is the string conversion specification.  The `*` causes the field width, an `int`, to be determined from the the next parameter after the format.  As OP mentions, this is the value of 4 from `stat[type].dent`.  The `s` conversion specification then gets the next parameter (`""`) and treats it a pointer to `char *`, which it is.  Thus `printf()` prints out `""`, pre-padding first with spaces, up to 4, as needed.  4 padding spaces are needed here as the string length of `""` is 0.  Net result: 4 spaces printed.

`"%s"`

This directive, also a string conversion specification, takes the next parameter, `buf`, assumes it is a `char *`, which it is, and prints its contents out.  Unclear if OP means it is *all* 0, if so, then nothing is printed.

`"\n"`

This final directive is simply a text, so `"\n"` is printed.